# Insider 16199 Edge browser

Tags: internet, browser

http://www.dslreports.com/tools is a broadband speed test. I use 4G and get 140 mps down and 40mps up with a moderate ping. In Edge the specific 4g test fails with an error explained as:

Error:1
The test noticed that uploading stopped. Here are some possible causes:

1. Connection drop during upload.
2. Very large upload buffering. Check "Staged Uploads", in the https://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/preferences. This will use increasingly large single uploads to determine the speed. Or change the upload method to 'web socket'.
3. Your connection is very poor. So poor that packet loss is causing many halts. Please review the ping radar plot by location. Is the ping time reasonable, both "best" and "worst"?
4. An Anti-virus product or browser extension is stalling or buffering the upload. Disable the most likely product, restart the browser, try again. Sophos AV, among others, are known to buffer all uploads (see explanation 2).

I immediately ran the same test using Chrome browser and it was perfect. So what is Edge doing to my internet connection??

Comment: I can't even open the test on dslreports. Have you tried another test, like [http://beta.speedtest.net/](http://beta.speedtest.net/)?

Comment: "So what is Edge doing to my internet connection??" - Nothing the problem is a likely an incompatible with Edge.

Comment: Yes could well be the the speedtest software is incompatible. Other test do work.